# How to write if statement to check for multiple text() values in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table column that performs a specific action depending on the text values. below os the html:

```
<td class="product"><span class="product">customer</span></td>
<td class="product"><span class="product">customer</span>, <span class="product">specifics</span></td>

<td class="product"><span class="product">admin</span>, <span class="product">specifics</span></td>
```

Now here, im trying to write a condition for certain text values. if the values are `"customer and/or specifics"`, I'd like to create a dialog box, else if the values are `"admin"`, I'd like to navigate to the main page. here is the js:

```
var rows = $(this).parents('tr');
if (rows.find('td.product').has('span.product').text() === 'customer') {

    alert('show dialog message');

} else {
    alert('navigate back to main page');
}
```

However, this code will only check for the values for `"customer"` (but obvious) and not for the remaining values. How can i check for all the text values and perform action accordingly? Any ideas??
Thanks

**EDIT:**

I just wanted to clarify few things:
the text val can hold multiple values like: `"customer, specifics,admin"` for one row and it could also hold just `"customer"` or just `"specifics"`. So if any of the text values contains the `admin` as a value, I'd redirect it to the main page..(the 2nd condition in my case). Only if the row contains values other than the `admin`, it should show a dialog message (1st condition in this case). Sorry for not being clear at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/ocju73ox/4/

```
var toredirect = false;
var showdialog = false;
//test scenarios
//var val = "admin";//works perfect
//var val = "customer, specifics"; //works perfect
//var val = "admin, specifics"; // shouuld redirect to main page, but calls dialog
var val = "admin, customer";// shouuld redirect to main page, but calls dialog

//var val = "customer, specifics";//works perfect
//var val = "customer";//works perfect

//rows.find('td.product').has('span.product').text();
// considering the text value is "admin, specifics" , 3rd <td>
alert(val);
if (checkif(val, "customer") || checkif(val, "specifics")) {
    showdialog = true;
}
if (checkif(val, "admin"))  {
   toredirect = true;
}

/*alert(toredirect);
alert(showdialog);*/

if (toredirect) {
    //redirect
    alert("will redirect");
    return false;
} else if (showdialog) {
    alert("will show dialog");
    //showdialog
}

function checkif(input, word) {
    if (input.indexOf(word) > -1) {       
        return true;     
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Revision asked 1: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/th3Lazfj/2/

Revision asked 2: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/th3Lazfj/4/

Comment: The text() it generates on calling "value = rows.find('td.product').has('span.product').text()" is : "customer,specifics". So ow if i try to check for a condition, "value == "customer" || value =="specifics"", it results into "false", but it should be true and generate the pop-up..is there any soln for this???

Comment: Yes wait i will fix that. The demo provided hadn't this case. give me some minutes to update.

Comment: let's see if this helps.tell me if something.

Comment: just one quick clarification, your code evaluates all the possible records on the page- the $.each() loop (if 20, it will scan all 20 records and generate results for each of one) and results into multiple pop-ups. hence i tried using the rows.find('td.product').has('span.product').text(); ( this will check for which row in the table was clicked and accordingly give the value). it does not quite work the same way it should. it gives correct results for values with admin, but fails when the <span> has  2 values eg: "customer", "specifics". am i going wrong here?? Thanks

Comment: check this out .Suppose that val is the scenario this will work .Check all possible values to see! http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/th3Lazfj/2/

Comment: almost close...but still looks like when val= "admin, specifics", it shows dialog, instead to main page. here is what i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/th3Lazfj/3/                                    so any value, having "admin" (be it a single value or multiple values) ideally to be redirected to main page..

Comment: Now we are ready ,check this revision http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/th3Lazfj/4/ ,hope this helps!

Comment: PERFECT!!! WORKED just the way i wanted..Thanks a lottt @Csdtesting for ur hard work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/2nd215c3/6/

```
var rows = $(this).parents('tr');
var arrClass = ["product","product","product","product"];
if (rows.find('td.product').has('span.product').text() === 'customer')
               {

               alert('show dialog message');

               }else{
               alert('navigate back to main page');}
//try this 
jQuery("span.product").each(function(){
$(this).text();

    if ($(this).text() === 'customer')
               {

               alert('show dialog message');

               }else{
               alert('navigate back to main page');}

})
```

Comment: this is using jQuery ...do you want like this ?